# TabBarController + CoreData + XML Drill down table on xcode 4.2

Tags: xml, uitableview, core-data, xcode4.2, tabbarcontroller

Well, i have to feed my application in this way:

TabBarController
|
|--- 1)TableView from xml using coreData --- 1.1)Detail View aftehr 2 choices
|
|--- 2)TableView (same xml) using coreData (but using other tags) --- 2.1)DetailView after 2 choice
|
|--- 3)MapView with google maps etcetc.

for the 3) i have no problem, it works.

My question is related to the point 1) and 2).

I've followed this guide: http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-core-data-uitableview-drill-down/
which explain how to create a drill down table from a xml file.

my xml has a similar structure with the xml in the file, and i need a table view who works in the same way.

But now in xcode 4.2 i want to use the storyboard but i've got some problem to adapt the code to the storyboard because the window is loaded in another way, and also i have some problem to use the appdelegate, because I have some error during the run of the application.

My question are:
1) How can i manage the classes and the code from the example to obtain a such complex app scheme?
2)Do I have to declare separates delegates for each parser?

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm having the same problem you had. I followed the same guide (from sallarp blog) but I cannot implement it with a UITabBarController. Can you please explain how you solved it?

Comment: uhm let's say I haven't solved it!
Now I'm using a simple unique Navigation Controller that handles the stuff read from the xml file, and I'm using the "toolbar" of the navigation controller with some button to switch to other views, and the result is pretty similar to the original idea!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest first:

1. Watching the Apple 2011 developer video on Storyboarding, then
2. Creating a quick test project using storyboarding and a single UITableview

Once you've got that basic flow/understanding, migrating your code might become clearer.

Comment: Ok, I've also started right from there, but how can I manage "multiple" coreData entities?
I mean: 1 coreData "scheme"
with:   2 coreData "examination"
Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using CoreData versions/migrations? A few really good WWDC videos in that area too.

Comment: no, i'm not using migrations.
anyway, i've solved the problem going around it. I'm using 1 single navigation controller that handle the coredata hierarchy and the xml parsing and i'm using the navigation toolbar instead of a tableviewcontroller. it's more simple...and it works XD